# Where are tag libraries stored?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tags

I'm looking at a Spring JSP project I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/spring-finance-manager/) and trying to learn from it.

I came across a file called `includes.jsp` composed of these lines:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Apparently, these are directives that declare a prefix for a given tag library. So for the tag library at `http://www.springframework.org/tags`, the prefix in our project will be `spring`.

The problem is, I went to the website `http://www.springframework.org/tags`, and it doesn't exist. The page returns an error. It seems like the project still works nonetheless. 
So where are these tag libraries actually being stored, and how can I find them (and what tags they contain)?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tld-files from the META-INF-directory of spring-webmcv-*.jar.

[Spring tags are described in the Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html). The sources can also be [found online at github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/resources/META-INF).

The taglibs are identified by URIs (Uniform Resource Identifier). URIs may look like URLs (Uniform Resource Locator) but these two are not the same. URIs might be e.g. URNs or OID just as well. You can read more about [defining custom tag libraries](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html) from the Java EE tutorial

Comment: Can you explain how the app still works even though the link to the tag libraries doesn't?